# Creating cohort-style data frame from set of observations

Tags: r, reshape

I'm new to R and have a simple question, as I'm still learning the style of R data manipulation/management.

I have a dataset of observations of basic clinical features (blood pressure, cholesterol, etc) over a period of time. Each observation has a patient ID and date, but are entered as separate line items. Something like this:

```
Patient ID    Date  Blood Pressure
         1 21/1/14             120
         1 19/3/14             134
         1  3/5/14             127
```

I want to transform the data such that for a given variable (e.g. blood pressure), I have a data frame with one line per patient and all of the blood pressure values observed throughout time in chronological order. Something like this:

```
Patient ID BP1 BP2 BP3 
         1 120 134 127
```

I want to do this because I want to be able to write code to select the mean of the first three observed blood pressures, for example.

Any advice or reading recommendations would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the desired formatting by reshaping your data with a number of methods including using the `reshape()` function in Base R or `dcast()` in the `reshape2` package, but it might be easier to just be able to get to your answer directly using a form of aggregation.  Here's one method using `ddply()` from the `plyr` package:

```
library(plyr)

df <- read.table(text="id  date  bp
1 21/1/14             120
1 19/3/14             134
1  3/5/14             127",header=TRUE)

df1 <- ddply(df, .(id), summarize, mean.bp = mean(bp[1:3]))

df1
#   id mean.bp
# 1  1     127
```

Of course, if you really just want to do what you asked about, you can do the following:

```
library(reshape2)

df$bp.id <- ave(df$id,df$id,FUN=function(x) paste0("BP",seq(along=x)))
df2 <- dcast(df[df$bp.id %in% paste0("BP",1:3)], id~bp.id, value.var="bp")    

df2
#   id BP1 BP2 BP3
# 1  1 120 134 127
```

Comment: Good use of `ave/dcast` Plus one.

Comment: I'm trying to use the second option you provided (using reshape2). Using the exact code you've written above, it returns the following error: Error in `[.data.frame`(df, df$bp.id %in% paste0("BP", 1:3)) : 
  undefined columns selected. Any thoughts? Each id has more than 3 bp observations (max is 14), and when I change 1:3 to 1:14 I still get the same error.

Comment: For some reason, I missed a comma but it still worked for me. Try this first: `df2 <- dcast(df, id~bp.id, value.var="bp") `.  If that doesn't work, try this `df2 <- dcast(df[df$bp.id %in% paste0("BP",1:3),], id~bp.id, value.var="bp")` or this `df2 <- dcast(df[grep("BP",df$bp.id),], id~bp.id, value.var="bp")`.

Answer (score 3):

```
 # example dataframe
id <- c(rep(1:4,25))
date <- c(rep("21/01/14",30),rep("21/01/14",30),rep("22/01/14",30),rep("23/01/14",10))
bp <- c(rnorm(100,100))
df <- data.frame(id,date,bp)

# reorder the dataframe
library(dplyr)
df2 <- group_by(df,id) # group by id
df2 <- arrange(df2, date) # order each group by date
df3 <- mutate(df2,   # add a colum with ascending number per for each group
              c = 1:length(date))

# use dcast
library(reshape2)
dcast(df3[,c(1,4,3)],id~c)
```

Answer (score 3):

With the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package (which has an improved implementation of the `melt` and `dcast` functions of [reshape2](/questions/tagged/reshape2)) you could do this as follows:

```
newdf <- dcast(setDT(df)[, idx := 1:.N, by = id], id ~ paste0("bp",idx), value.var = "bp")
```

Or utilizing the new `rowid` function:

```
newdf <- dcast(setDT(df), id ~ rowid(prefix="bp",id), value.var = "bp")
```

both options give the same result:

```
> newdf
   id bp1 bp2 bp3
1:  1 120 134 129
2:  2 110 124 119
```

---

But as @SamDickson said, when you want to calculate the mean of (for example) the first two blood pressure measurements, then you can also add a new variable to your existing dataframe `df` with:

```
# using base R
df$first2mn <- ave(df$bp, df$id, FUN = function(x) mean(x[1:2])) 
# using data.table
setDT(df)[, first2mn := mean(bp[1:2]), id]
```

which both give:

```
> df
   id    date  bp first2mn
1:  1 21/1/14 120      127
2:  1 19/3/14 134      127
3:  1  3/5/14 129      127
4:  2 21/1/14 110      117
5:  2 19/3/14 124      117
6:  2  3/5/14 119      117
```

Or just calculate the mean with:

```
# using base R
aggregate(bp ~ id, df, function(x) mean(x[1:2])) 
# using data.table
setDT(df)[, .(bp = mean(bp[1:2])), id]
```

which both give:

```
  id  bp
1  1 127
2  2 117
```

---

Used data:

```
df <- read.table(text="id  date  bp
1 21/1/14             120
1 19/3/14             134
1  3/5/14             129
2 21/1/14             110
2 19/3/14             124
2  3/5/14             119", header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have provided a number of methods for calculating the mean across groups. A [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314336/extract-the-maximum-value-within-each-group-in-a-dataframe) provides a number of methods for calculating group level maxima. You would need to replace `max` with `mean` in these answers.

Here is an additional method for reshaping wide using the base R function `reshape`.

Use the data.frame provided by @jaap, add a variable for counting the observations by ID:

```
df$times <- ave(df$bp, df$id, FUN=seq_along)
```

Now, perform the reshape, dropping the unwanted date variable:

```
reshape(df, direction="wide", drop="date", timevar="times")
  id bp.1 bp.2 bp.3
1  1  120  134  129
4  2  110  124  119
```