# r minimum value of a factor

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 2 columns: user and seconds.  User is a categorical variable, with each user being assigned a number.  A user can appear multiple times in the dataset.  Seconds represent the amount of time spent on a page.

I have already used `factor()` so that R recognizes the user variable as categorical.  However, I can't figure out how to find the minimum number of seconds for each user.  that is, I can find the overall minimum number of seconds, but I can't find User 1's minimum or User 2's minimum.  Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Data

```
user    seconds
1   35
1   30
1   25
1   20
2   15
1   15
2   10
1   10
2   5
1   5
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract the maximum value within each group in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314336/extract-the-maximum-value-within-each-group-in-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(Min=min(seconds)), by = user]
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(user) %>%
    summarise(Min = min(seconds))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's basic content of R.

```
tapply(df1$seconds, df1$user, min)
# 1 2 
# 5 5
```

Comment: Thanks! I am very new to R and to computing.  Still picking up the hang of things.

Answer (score 1):

assume that your data is in a dataframe "x"

aggregate(seconds ~ user, data = x, FUN=min)