# How to extract the min/max values in a dataframe to display data as a ribbon?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have several sets of data stored in a data frame. For the sake of this question, I provide below a way to generate this data frame, but IRL, I only have the `merged` data frame, not the intermediate ones.

```
x <- seq.POSIXt(from = strptime("1970-01-01 00:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                to = strptime("1970-01-01 00:05:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                by = "10 sec")

x <- rep(x, each = 3)
y <- c()

set.seed(1)

for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  y <- c(y, runif(1, min = 0, max = i))
}

my.data.frame1 <- data.frame(x, y, data = as.factor("data1"))

y <- c()
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  y <- c(y, runif(1, min = length(x) - i, max = length(x)))
}

my.data.frame2  <- data.frame(x, y, data = as.factor("data2"))

merged <- rbind(my.data.frame1, my.data.frame2)

ggplot(merged, aes(x, y, color = data)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

So for each type of data (data1 and data2), and for each date value on the x axis, I have 3 y values.

The plot looks (bad) like this:

[image]

What I want to do is to plot a `geom_ribbon` of the data but I don't know how to do it.

I first tried to extract the min and max values with an `aggregate` function as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314336/how-to-extract-the-maximum-value-within-each-group-in-a-data-frame) for each time and build a new data frame without duplicate x values but couldn't make it work.

Can anyone help?

**Edit:**

The code I tried with `aggregate` is this one:

```
aggregate(y ~ x, data = merged, max)
```

(Same for the min). But this does not make the difference between the data1 set and the data2 set. I know I could subset, but I guess it can be done using the "by" argument. Just couldn't make it work.

Comment: Your approach with `aggregate` sounds like a good one.  Can you add the code you tried so we can help troubleshoot?

Comment: Updated question :)

Comment: I think you want to aggregate by "data" and "x", which you can do by putting multiple variables on the RHS of the tilde: `aggregate(y ~ data + x, data = merged, max)`.  Per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12064297/2461552) you can get the min and max at the same time in the same data.frame (helpful for plotting) so try `aggregate(y ~ data + x, data = merged, FUN = function(x) c(min.y = min(x), max.y = max(x)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track, and need to aggregate by both `data` and `x` instead of just `x`.

You can either calculate the `min` and `max` by group separately in two `aggregate` calls and then merge or do both at the same time.  For the second approach you'll need an additional step to get the output of the two functions into separate columns.

```
my.new.df = aggregate(y ~ data + x, data = merged, FUN = function(x) c(min = min(x), max = max(x)))

# Get the min and max as separate columns
my.new.df = as.data.frame(as.list(my.new.df))

ggplot(my.new.df, aes(x, fill = data)) + 
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = y.min, ymax = y.max), alpha = 0.6)
```

You can also make the plot directly using `stat = "summary"` in `geom_ribbon` instead of making an aggregate dataset for plotting.

```
ggplot(merged, aes(x, y, fill = data)) + 
    geom_ribbon(alpha = 0.6, stat = "summary", fun.ymax = max, fun.ymin = min)
```