# Conditional Maximum in data frame: pmax value based on defined condition

Tags: r, max

Consider the following data

```
F1 <- c(1,1,1,0,1)
F2 <- c(10,20,15,7,20)
F3 <- c('A', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'A')
F4 <- c(9,6,20,20,20)
F5 <- c(2,1,21,8,7)
df1 <- data.frame(F1,F2,F3,F4,F5)
```

When `df1$F1==1` I want to obtain the max between `$F4`, `$F5` and `$F2`, but only consider `$F2` if the `$F3` factor is `A` or `B`. Otherwise write `NA`

```
df1$max <- with(df1, ifelse(F1==1, pmax(F2[F3_condition],F4,F5), NA))
```

How can one account for the `F3_condition` where er consider on factor `A` or `B`?

So `$max` will take the following values: `c(10,6,21,NA,20)`

I have reviewed a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314336/how-to-extract-the-maximum-value-within-each-group-in-a-data-frame), but it does not exactly deal with the specific condition I require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another `ifelse` to modify `F2` vector before using `pmax` (replace corresponding values with `-Inf` and it will be less than most of the values):

```
df1$max <- with(df1, ifelse(F1==1, pmax(ifelse(F3 %in% c("A", "B"), F2, -Inf), F4, F5), NA))
df1$max
# [1] 10  6 21 NA 20
```

---

Alternatively, replace it with `NA` and use `na.rm = T` in `pmax` depending on if you have `NA`s in F4 and F5:

```
df1$max <- with(df1, ifelse(F1==1, pmax(ifelse(F3 %in% c("A", "B"), F2, NA), F4, F5, na.rm = T), NA))
df1$max
# [1] 10  6 21 NA 20
```

Answer (score 1):

If all values of F4 and F5 are non-negative, as in the example, and F1 is only composed of 0s and 1s, then the following will also work:

```
with(df1, pmax(F2 * (F3 %in% c("A", "B")) , F4, F5) * NA^(!F1))
[1] 10  6 21 NA 20
```

Here, `F2 * (F3 %in% c("A", "B"))` returns 0 for F2 values where F3 is not A or B. `pmax` calculates the maximum for the variables in each row. Then, the resulting vector is multiplied by `NA^(!F1)` which returns 1 when F1 != 0 and NA when F1 == 0.