# Extract a value in column A given the maximum value in column B within each group (column C) in an R dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, subset

My question is related to [Extract the maximum value within each group in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25314336/4581200).

- The question there is essentially: how do you select the max value in one column based on repeated groups in a separate column in the same data frame?
- In that post, user EDi [provides a ton of examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25314565/4581200) for how to accomplish this task.

My question: **how do I accomplish the same task, but instead of reporting the max value, I instead report a value in a third column associated with that max value?**

For example:

- Assume I have a data.frame:

  ```
  Group  Value   Year
  A      12      1933
  A      10      2010
  B      3       1935
  B      5       1978
  B      6       2011
  C      1       1954
  D      3       1933
  D      4       1978
  ```
- For each level of my grouping variable, I wish to extract the *year* that the maximum value occurred. The result should thus be a data frame with one row per level of the grouping variable:

  ```
  Group  Year
  A      1933
  B      2011
  C      1954
  D      1978
  ```

I know I could use any of the answers from EDi's post mentioned above and then just use something like `which`,`match` or `sapply` to figure out the year, but that seems too sloppy.

**Is there a quick way to extract a value in column A given the maximum value in column B within each group (column C) in a dataframe?**

Update: Could someone please provide a base R solution?

Comment: Please explain your downvote. This question is fairly well-written, it provides an example, it's on topic, it demonstrates previous effort and searching, and it aptly follows the rules (i.e., open a new question vs. asking follow-up questions in comments). WHAT GIVES?!

Comment: Added base R solution to answer below.

Comment: Thanks, @KristofferWintherBalling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R and a `data.table` solution:

```
df <- structure(list(Group = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D"
), Value = c(12L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L), Year = c(1933L, 
2010L, 1935L, 1978L, 2011L, 1954L, 1933L, 1978L)), .Names = c("Group", 
"Value", "Year"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

# Base R - use aggregate to get max Value per group, then merge with df
merge(df, aggregate(Value ~ Group, df, max), by.all = c("Group", "Value"))[
  , c("Group", "Year")]

#   Group Year
# 1     A 1933
# 2     B 2011
# 3     C 1954
# 4     D 1978

# data.table solution
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, .SD[which.max(Value), .(Year)], by = Group]

#    Group Year
# 1:     A 1933
# 2:     B 2011
# 3:     C 1954
# 4:     D 1978
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Group) %>% slice(which.max(Value)) %>% select(-Value)

#Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
#Groups: Group [4]

#   Group  Year
#  <fctr> <int>
#1      A  1933
#2      B  2011
#3      C  1954
#4      D  1978
```

Note this only keeps one max value per group if ties exist.

---

A method that keeps tied max values:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Group) %>% filter(Value == max(Value)) %>% select(-Value)

#Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
#Groups: Group [4]

#   Group  Year
#  <fctr> <int>
#1      A  1933
#2      B  2011
#3      C  1954
#4      D  1978
```