# Column in table consists of lists, for each row, find minimum of list and append to new column

Tags: r, dataframe

As the title says, I have a column 'values' that has a list of values for each entry. I want to find the minimum value in the list for each row and append it in a new column. Below is what I've tried (among other things) based on this answer [Extract the maximum value within each group in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314336/extract-the-maximum-value-within-each-group-in-a-dataframe).
Unfortunately, I only manage to find the minimum of the entire column and apply that same minimum to every row.

```
df <- df[,'minVal' := min(unlist(df$values))]
```

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data (ideally a `dput()` of some sort).

Comment: My apologies, its been a while since I've used Stackoverflow. Eric has answered below and his example captures the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered, `min` will return the minimum for the whole column. Sounds like each entry is a list, and when you unlist it you will get a vector of all values, of which `min` will return the minimum.

Instead, you could `apply` `min` to each entry in the list, to get the minimum.

In addition, the `:=` assignment is in place. You don't need to assign back to `df` using `<-`, and within the `data.table` you can refer to columns directly, don't use `df$values`.

Try this:

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(a = 1:3, values = list(1:6, 2:4, 9:11))
df[, minVal := sapply(values, min)]
df
#    a      values minVal
# 1: 1 1,2,3,4,5,6      1
# 2: 2       2,3,4      2
# 3: 3     9,10,11      9
```