# Running ifelse statement by a variable

Tags: r

I am trying to run an ifelse statement with a by group and cannot see how to do it in R.

For example if I have

```
ID  ORDER
1   1
2   1
3   1
3   2
3   3
6   1
7   1
7   2
```

I want to create a column which gives a 1 if order = max(order), and a 0 otherwise for each ID. So overall would give

```
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1
```

My ifelse statement is therefore

```
ifelse(ORDER == max(ORDER), 1, 0)
```

How would I do this for each ID variable (preferably without a for loop)?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at `dplyr::group_by`

Comment: Use the `ave()` function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract the maximum value within each group in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314336/extract-the-maximum-value-within-each-group-in-a-dataframe)

Comment: ... possible duplicate of a duplicate... :)

Comment: That link is not a duplicate of this question.  There's no extraction happening here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `base R` you can use `ave()` for the grouping and do

```
with(df, ave(ORDER, ID, FUN = function(x) x == max(x)))
#[1] 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1
```

Thanks to @RichScriven.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 7L), ORDER = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("ID", "ORDER"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Or just `function(x) x == max(x)` since `ORDER` is already numeric

Answer (score 1):

```
library('data.table')
setDT(df1) # make df1 as data.table by reference
# check for the condition and convert it to integer
df1[, m_ord := as.integer(ORDER == max(ORDER)), by = .(ID)]  
df1

#    ID ORDER m_ord
# 1:  1     1     1
# 2:  2     1     1
# 3:  3     1     0
# 4:  3     2     0
# 5:  3     3     1
# 6:  6     1     1
# 7:  7     1     0
# 8:  7     2     1
```

**Data:**

```
df1 <- read.table(text='ID  ORDER
1   1
                  2   1
                  3   1
                  3   2
                  3   3
                  6   1
                  7   1
                  7   2', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea that does not require any grouping. You first order your data frame and then find the duplicates, i.e.

```
df1 <- df[order(df$ID, df$ORDER),]
as.integer(!duplicated(df1$ID, fromLast = TRUE))
#[1] 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1
```

**NOTE:** The above method assumes that the maximum value only occurs once (Thanks to Ryan for commenting)

Comment: Although if `ORDER == max(ORDER)` for more than 1 row this will give a different result than the other answers.

Comment: @Ryan yes I saw It but thought to share this as It uses a different method than grouping and aggregating which might be useful to other similar use cases. Let me add it as a note in my answer though.