# Why is the result of `==` of class integer when used inside ave()?

Tags: r, grouping

This post is based on this question: [Running ifelse statement by a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50989573/running-ifelse-statement-by-a-variable)

Given some data

```
  col1 col2
1    B   10
2    B    7
3    C    7
4    D    1
5    A    3
6    D    2
```

to which we want to add a new column that indicates whether the value of 'col2' is the maximum of 'col2' grouped by 'col1'.

In `base R` one can use `transform` and `ave`

```
transform(df, new_col = ave(col2, col1, FUN = function(x) x == max(x)))
  col1 col2 new_col
1    B   10       1
2    B    7       0
3    C    7       1
4    D    1       0
5    A    3       1
6    D    2       1
```

My question is why 'new_col' is of type integer and not logical?

@RichScriven pointed out in the comments that that's because 'col2' is already numeric but I don't understand that.

Thanks!

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c("B", "B", "C", "D", "A", "D"), col2 = c(10L, 
7L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 2L)), .Names = c("col1", "col2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ave` will return an object of the same class as `x` if it can be coerced

```
with(df, ave(col2, col1, FUN = function(x) T))
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
with(df, ave(col2, col1, FUN = function(x) 'a'))
# [1] "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "a"

df$col2 <- as.logical(df$col2)
with(df, ave(col2, col1, FUN = function(x) T))
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE



df$col2 <- as.factor(df$col2)
with(df, ave(col2, col1, FUN = function(x) T))
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
# Levels: TRUE
```

Edit: It appears that it will coerce to a "higher" class but not a "lower" class. Where "higher" and "lower" is determined by the ordering given in `?c` (below).

```
df$col2 <- as.logical(df$col2)
with(df, ave(col2, col1, FUN = function(x) 1))
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

> NULL < raw < logical < integer < double < complex < character < list <
>   expression

Comment: The rules for mixed types in arithmetic are described in `?Arithmetic`.  The rules for combining different types using `c()` are given in `?c`.  Not sure which set of rules determines results in `ave()`.

Comment: if you want to see something funny try `with(df, ave(as.character(col2), col1, FUN = function(x) T))`

Comment: The documentation states that the first parameter should be numeric, and then states that the output will be numeric, but as we've seen it's true only if the input is as expected by the function.