# How do I get R to return the highest value of column B for each unique variable in column A?

Tags: r

I have this dataframe.

```
A <- c('x','y','y','x')
B <- c(2,4,3,4)
example <- data.frame(A, B)
```

I would like to return the highest value (B) for each group in A, ie. return 4 for x and 4 for y. Hoping someone could help me write R code to do this. I am a beginner and first time poster, I apologise if this is a silly question!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract the maximum value within each group in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314336/extract-the-maximum-value-within-each-group-in-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 4):

You could use a tidyverse approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

result <- example %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  summarise(maxvalue = max(B))

result
```

This groups your data by the value of column `A`, then finds the maximum value for each unique value in `A`. Output:

```
  A     maxvalue
  <fct>    <dbl>
1 x            4
2 y            4
```

Comment: Wow, how easy! Thank you!

Comment: No worries! Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(cbind(maxvalue = B) ~ A, example, max)
```

-ouptut

```
  A maxvalue
1 x        4
2 y        4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option using `tapply` + `stack`

```
with(
  example,
  rev(stack(tapply(B,A,max)))
)
```

gives

```
  ind values
1   x      4
2   y      4
```