# Find the maximum value for a specific value in a column?

Tags: r, dataframe, max

I've got a data frame with 34 columns and 12,964 rows, two of these columns are Gene.Name and Mutation_Frequency. For example:

| Gene.Name | Mutation_Frequency |
| --- | --- |
| CTLA4 | 0 |
| TP53 | 4 |
| CTLA4 | 2 |
| CTLA4 | 2 |
| TP53 | 4 |
| TP53 | 6 |

I now want to create a column called "Highest_Mutation_Frequency" which tells me the highest mutation frequency for the Gene.Name, and puts it in a new column, like this:

| Gene.Name | Mutation_Frequency | Highest_Mutation_Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CTLA4 | 0 | 2 |
| TP53 | 4 | 6 |
| CTLA4 | 2 | 2 |
| CTLA4 | 2 | 2 |
| TP53 | 0 | 6 |
| TP53 | 6 | 6 |

I realize I could probably use the max() command, but I'm not sure how to implement this. As always, any help is appreciated!

Edit: Although this is quite similar to another question:
[Select the row with the maximum value in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558328/select-the-row-with-the-maximum-value-in-each-group)
this question also involves producing unique rows and placing them in another data frame.

Comment: Try looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314336/extract-the-maximum-value-within-each-group-in-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option with `base R`

```
aggregate(cbind(Highest_Mutation_Frequency = Mutation_Frequency) ~ Gene.Name, data, FUN = max)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(Gene.Name) %>%
  mutate(Highest_Mutation_Frequency = max(Mutation_Frequency))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another base R option using `unique` + `ave`

```
unique(
  transform(
    df,
    Highest_Mutation_Frequency = ave(Mutation_Frequency,Gene.Name,FUN = max)
  )[c("Gene.Name","Highest_Mutation_Frequency")]
)
```